# Do Karma Kshyam (nullification of karma) happens in all avasthas?

Tags: scripture, karma, avastha

Afaik, there are at least five states for humans. They are Jagarth (wakeful), Swapna (dream), Shushupti (deep sleep), turiya, and thuriyatheetha.

I know that Karma Kshyam happens in both Jagrath and [Swapna avastha](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-vasistha-english/d/doc118174.html). But I did not know whether other avasthas of human allows Karma Kshyam.

Are there any scriptural statements that says whether other avasthas allow karma kshyam or not?